# Error creating a session variable in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am creating a procedure where it receives two parameters: `p_user` and `p_id`.

```
create or replace procedure user (p_user numeric, p_ip varchar(20))
as $$
begin 
    set session.id_user= p_user;
    set session.ip = p_ip;
end;
$$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```

I call the created procedure:

```
call user (1, '127.0.0.1');
```

I perform the verification query:

```
select current_setting('session.id_user'), current_setting('session.ip');
```

And I get as a result:

```
current_setting: p_user
current_setting: p_ip
```

And not the values ​​reported in the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FORMAT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function for this:

```
create or replace procedure myproc (p_user numeric, p_ip varchar(20))
as $$
begin 
    execute format('set session.id_user=%s', p_user) ;
    execute format('set session.ip=%L', p_ip) ;
end;
$$ 
language 'plpgsql';
CREATE PROCEDURE

call myproc(1, '127.0.0.1');
CALL

select current_setting('session.id_user'), current_setting('session.ip');
 current_setting | current_setting 
-----------------+-----------------
 1               | 127.0.0.1
(1 row)
```